# Apexcharts radial chart counter-clockwise progress bar

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts

I am using React Apexcharts to create a radial chart. By default, the progress bar goes in a clockwise direction but I need it to go counter-clockwise. Is there any option property available I can use?

**What my graph looks like now:**

[image]

**What I need it to look like (bar going in opposite direction):**

[image]

**My options object:**

```js
let options = {
        colors: ["#857EFF"],
        plotOptions: {
            radialBar: {
            hollow: {
                margin: 0,
                size: "70%",
                background: "#293450"
            },
            track: {
                dropShadow: {
                    enabled: true,
                    top: 2,
                    left: 0,
                    blur: 4,
                    opacity: 0.15,
                }
            },
            dataLabels: {
                name: {
                offsetY: -10,
                color: "#fff",
                fontSize: "13px"
                },
                value: {
                color: "#fff",
                fontSize: "30px",
                show: true
                }
            }
            }
        },
        fill: {
            type: "gradient",
            gradient: {
            shade: "dark",
            type: "vertical",
            gradientToColors: ["#05E996"],
            stops: [0, 100]
            }
        },
        stroke: {
            lineCap: "round"
        },
       labels: ["Progress"]
    }
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I've been looking for an answer for this Problem without any success. Today i've successfully created a workaround.

The Apex Radialbar just hardcoded always goes clockwise, no matter what you do because it is always going from startAngle to endAngle using +1.

So using startAngle -360 and endAngle 0 will have no effect.

Essentially, you want to create the Radialbar and mirror it on Y axis and then remirror everyhting you want to keep normal, back to normal. However you need to transform the components usually back in place.

You can also try only selecting the Radialbar and only rotating that, however i find getting the other components back in the correct place using "transformX" is usually easier.

so lets say you want a Bar from -360 to 90 but counter-clockwise,
create a Radialbar from 0 to 270 and then use the following CSS transforms.

Here is the example Radialbar from the Angular Documentation with a counter-clockwise bar.

TIPP:
Use exact classifiers and unique, here in ng-deep with

```
counter-clockwise svg
```

Because once you use ng-deep you cannot unset it, unless you modify the document directly, so when you switch views you might have unwanted sideeffects.

---

Mirrored

[image: Mirrored]

Original

[image: Original]

Answer (score 0):

Change `startAngle` and `endAngle` options
https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/plotoptions/radialbar/

```
plotOptions: {
    radialBar: {  
       startAngle: -360,
       endAngle: 0,
       ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking to do this same thing and after reading apexcharts docs as well as experimenting around with it I don't think it's currently possible.